# Perl + Tk: pass a (Scrolled/Listbox) widget reference to a subroutine

Tags: perl, reference, tk-toolkit

I have a problem passing Listbox references from a subroutine to another subroutine. What I want to do in the end is: upon selection in BoxA find out what the value of the selected item is and select someting in boxB based on that value.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Tk;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $mw = MainWindow -> new();
my @arr = qw(1 2 3 4 5);
my $button = $mw -> Button (-text=>"Push me", -command => \&buttonCall) -> pack;

sub callee{
        my $boxARef = $_[0];
        my $boxBRef = $_[1];
        my $index = $boxARef -> curselection();
        $boxBRef -> selectionSet($index);
}

sub buttonCall{
        my $boxA = $mw -> Listbox(-exportselection=>0, -selectmode => 'browse') -> pack;
        $boxA -> insert('end', @arr);
        my $boxB = $mw -> Listbox(-exportselection=>0, -selectmode => 'multiple') -> pack;
        $boxB -> insert('end', @arr);
        $boxA -> bind ('<<ListboxSelect>>' => [\&callee,\$boxA,\$boxB] );
}

MainLoop;
```

Executing the code results in:

```
Tk::Error: Can't call method "selectionSet" on unblessed reference at ./stack-test.pl line 14.
 <<ListboxSelect>>
 (command bound to event)
```

I am quite new to Perl and will appreciate any help with references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

If you use the `[coderef, arg, arg...]` form to specify a Tk callback, the coderef will always be called with the widget that triggered the event passed as first argument. So that is your `$_[0]`. The two args you want to pass will end up in `$_[1]`and `$_[2]`.

Your variables `$boxA` and `$boxB` are references already, but you pass them with an additional `\` operator. That means you would have to dereference them in your callback sub before trying to call Tk methods on them. - Or drop the `\` in the callback definition:

```
use Tk;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $mw = MainWindow -> new();
my @arr = qw(1 2 3 4 5);
my $button = $mw -> Button (-text=>"Push me", -command => \&buttonCall) -> pack;

sub callee{
        my $boxARef = $_[1];
        my $boxBRef = $_[2];
        my $index = $boxARef -> curselection();
        $boxBRef -> selectionSet($index);
}

sub buttonCall{
        my $boxA = $mw -> Listbox(-exportselection=>0, -selectmode => 'browse') -> pack;
        $boxA -> insert('end', @arr);
        my $boxB = $mw -> Listbox(-exportselection=>0, -selectmode => 'multiple') -> pack;
        $boxB -> insert('end', @arr);
        $boxA -> bind ('<<ListboxSelect>>' => [\&callee,$boxA,$boxB] );
}

MainLoop;
```

Comment: Good catch! I missed that they forgot to dereference the references in `callee`.

Comment: I didn't know the widget that triggered the event is under $_[0]. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be something strange going on with the references to the boxes created in `buttonCall()`. The following works for me:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow -> new();
my @arr = qw(1 2 3 4 5);
my $boxA;
my $boxB;
my $button = $mw -> Button (
    -text=>"Push me",
    -command => sub { buttonCall( \$boxA, \$boxB ) }
) -> pack;

sub callee{
    my ( $boxARef, $boxBRef ) = @_;

    my $index = $$boxARef -> curselection();
    $$boxBRef -> selectionSet($index);
}

sub buttonCall{
    my ( $boxARef, $boxBRef ) = @_;
    if ( !defined $$boxARef ) {
        $$boxARef = $mw -> Listbox(-exportselection=>0, -selectmode => 'browse') -> pack;
        $$boxARef -> insert('end', @arr);
        $$boxBRef = $mw -> Listbox(
            -exportselection=>0, -selectmode => 'multiple'
        ) -> pack;
        $$boxBRef -> insert('end', @arr);
        $$boxARef -> bind ('<<ListboxSelect>>' => sub { callee( $boxARef, $boxBRef) });
    }
}

MainLoop;
```